Parasite attracted to salt in the human body horror film!
So when I was young I remember seeing a movie on tv about a parasite bug of some kind that was attracted to salt in the human body. 
I believe it came from the ocean or something but I can’t remember it’s origin.
Two scenes I remember are:

a woman trying to cut the parasites out of her arm with a knife. 
seeing dead bodies the parasites had killed with holes in their skin, especially the kidneys (due to their high salt content). 

And possibly 

a scene with a few dead bodies on the beach. 

I’m almost positive it’s not the movie “The Bay” which is sort of similar in plot but was much more horrific. It’s also not the movie “Growth”, or that Star Trek episode about the salt loving alien.
The one I’m talking about was older and had more of a 70s B movie feel to it, which is probably how it was on TV. 

Well I’m starting to think this movie was just some cheap junk i saw on tv. It had a good plot, but apparently not enough to deserve a vhs/dvd. But I’m sad I couldn’t at least find a title. If it doesn’t get answered in a few weeks/months, I’ll just answer it with this comment.

It doesn't 100% match up (actually, more like 20-30%), but the first episode of Star Trek: The Original Series deals with a salt-eating monster that attacks the crew of the Enterprise, released in 1966.  The Man Trap

When Professor Crater arrives, he is reluctant to be examined, telling
  Kirk that they only require salt tablets. Before McCoy can complete
  the examination, they hear a scream from outside. They find Darnell
  dead, with red ring-like mottling on his face and a plant root visible
  in his mouth; Nancy says that she was unable to stop Darnell from
  tasting the plant. On board Enterprise, Spock (Leonard Nimoy) analyzes
  the plant. He confirms that it is poisonous, but the mottling is not a
  symptom. McCoy conducts a medical exam, and together with Spock
  determines that Darnell died after all the salt was drained from his
  body.


No it was definitely not that episode of Star Trek. I am a huge Star Trek fan and remember that episode. It is not what I am talking about.

More like 1%..if that.

@Paulie_D shrugs

I did think of that episode when I read the title, but the rest of the question seems to eliminate the possibility.

From Within, an Outer Limits episode has salt-eating parasites. Low-budget, so it might account for the 1970s feel. 

Close, but no cigar. I even watched the episode to be sure. But alas it’s not what I remember. The parasites in the movie/show I watched did not control minds. They simply ate people from the inside. Thanks anyways though!
